# Inequality between probabilities

Tags: probability

Consider $x_{s}$ which is a random variable from a standard normal distribution, and given values $w_{s}>0$ for $s=1,2,...,r,$ where $r$ is some finite number. We have that $$(\sum_{s=1}^rw_{s}x_{s}^2)\geq(w_{min}\sum_{s=1}^rx_{s}^2)$$ where $w_{min}=min_{s}(w_{s})$.

What inequality holds between the probabilities $Pr(\sum_{s=1}^rw_{s}x_{s}^2>c)$ and $Pr(w_{min}\sum_{s=1}^rx_{s}^2>c),$ where $c$ is a positive given value?

Answer (score 0):

As you've found, $w_{\mathrm{min}}\sum_{s=1}^r\mathsf{X}_s^2\le\sum_{s=1}^rw_s\mathsf{X}_s^2$, hence if the LHS is larger than $c$ then certainly the RHS is as well.
Thus we have that $\big\{w_{\mathrm{min}}\sum_{s=1}^r\mathsf{X}_s^2>c\big\}\subseteq\big\{\sum_{s=1}^rw_s\mathsf{X}_s^2>c\big\}$ and hence $\mathbb{P}\big(w_{\mathrm{min}}\sum_{s=1}^r\mathsf{X}_s^2>c\big)\le\mathbb{P}\big(\sum_{s=1}^rw_s\mathsf{X}_s^2>c\big)$

Comment: Thank you Asbjørn for your helpful response.